# '/media/disk/sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, gradle

I have imported project from `Eclipse` to`Android Studio` but the gradle building always fails because of above error. I don't understand what is the error.

Here is my `gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 7
    targetSdkVersion 19
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
     }
   }
 }

    dependencies {

compile project(':signaturePad')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile files('libs/NineOldAndroid-2.4.0.jar')
compile files('libs/picasso-2.3.3.jar')
}
```

I have tried changing my `buildtoolsversion` but it is not working.
For every build tools version it gives the same error.
I have also tried `Invalidate Chace and Restart` but still no result.
I have also tried uninstalling the `buildtools` and reinstalling it again but still no result.

Here is the error which is occured always
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line to gradle.properties

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

Comment: Where is gradle.properties file located. I have found gradle-wrapper.properties file @Saurabh sharma

Comment: There is no gradle.properties file in my gradle scripts and also I am not able to create a new file @ Saurabh sharma